# Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $h(h(x))=x$, and $a$,$b$ and $c$ are nonzero real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, rational-functions, function-and-relation-composition, mobius-transformation

Suppose that $a,b$ and $c$ are nonzero real numbers. Define
$$h(x) = \frac{ax+b}{bx+c}$$
for $x\neq -\frac cb$. Determine all triples $(a,b,c)$ for which $h(h(x)) =x$ for every real number $x\neq -\tfrac cb$, and $h(x)\neq-\frac cb$.

To start off, I don't know what it means to define $h(x)$, so I just tried solving.

$$h(x)=h^{-1}(x)$$
$$\frac{ax+b}{bx+c}=\frac{b-cx}{xb-a}$$

From this form I can see that $$a=-c$$ but I do not know how to find $b$ or how to find all triples $(a,b,c)$.

How would I solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Kolmin, the title should not contain $\LaTeX$, it becomes difficult to search.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Ok. Just to know. Is it a well-agreed point on meta? Is there a link to a meta discussion about it? Because it is the first time I face a complaint concerning titles with MathJaX. (I am not sure that the search is actually heavily impaired)

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: It's ok to have LaTeX in the title, you'd be amazed at what Google can do (I speak from experience).

Comment: @Kolmin, see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/using-mathjax-tex-in-the-titles-of-questions-yes-or-no). By the way, my opinion is - it is better to avoid $\LaTeX$ as far as possible (have to compromise in inevitable cases), and here $\LaTeX$ is unnecessary.

Comment: @Kolmin, look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/why-no-use-displaystyle-in-titles) also.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Ok, thanks a lot for the links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach. First write out what $h(h(x))$ is
$$h(h(x))=h\left(\frac{ax+b}{bx+c}\right)=\frac{a\left(\tfrac{ax+b}{bx+c}\right)+b}{b\left(\frac{ax+b}{bx+c}\right)+c}=\frac{a(ax+b)+b(bx+c)}{b(ax+b)+c(bx+c)}.$$
Next set this equal to $x$ and clear out the numerator to get
$$a(ax+b)+b(bx+c)=x(b(ax+b)+c(bx+c))=b(a+c)x^2+(b^2+c^2)x,$$
and moving everything to one side then yields a quadratic equation in $x$
$$b(a+c)x^2+(c^2-a^2)x-b(a+c)=0,$$
which must hold for all $x$. This only happens when all coefficients are $0$, so we must have
$$b(a+c)=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad c^2-a^2=0.$$
This is true if and only if $a=-c$, or $a=c$ and $b=0$. The latter cannot occur as $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$ must all be non-zero, so the triplets $(a,b,c)$ for which $h(h(x))=x$ holds are precisely the triplets for which $c=-a$.

Comment: I overlooked that, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$h(h(x))={1 \left( {\frac {a \left( ax+b \right) }{bx+c}}+b \right)  \left( {
\frac {b \left( ax+b \right) }{bx+c}}+c \right) ^{-1}}
$$

Comment: I tried simplifying the composition of functions like this too and ended up with the same result a=-c.

Comment: yes and i was downvoted